# LibGDX Box2D player is stumbling

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to program a simple 2D platformer, and I want the player to go over some platforms. Unfortunately, my player stumbles after some platforms for no reason:

[image]

And that's clearly not what I want. The only thing I can imagine is that the boxes aren't the same height for some reason... But how to fix that? Here's some of my code:

**createPlatform...**

```
public static Body createPlatform(World world, int x, int y) {
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(x, y));
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(1, 1);
    Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    body.createFixture(shape, Constants.GROUND_DENSITY);
    body.resetMassData();
    PlatformUserData userData = new PlatformUserData(1, 1, Constants.GROUND_IMAGE_PATH);
    body.setUserData(userData);
    shape.dispose();
    return body;
}
```

**Runner.java - act()**

```
@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
    body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(10f,0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have the ground made of multiple sections, the collision detection framework might detect the edge of the next block, like it was a little bit highrt than the previous. This is a computation error which happens with every sliding object sometimes. This is why they often set the player's shape to be an ellipse, and freeze the rotation of the object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the player fictions against the ground so velocity is greater than the friction support so the body stumbs.

You have to put:

```
body.setFixedRotation(true);
```

Or go down the value of the friction.